# count items in cart different on_sale

Tags: php, sql, shopping-cart, cart, prestashop-1.6

I am using prestashop 1.6 and I create a function into classes/Cart.php, This one count items in shopping-cart but that items are products without discount or reduction price.

```
/* @return int Cart Item not on_sale
*/
public function getTotalItems()
{
    $total_items = 0;

    $total_items = (int)Db::getInstance()->getValue('
        SELECT SUM(`quantity`)
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_product`
        WHERE `id_cart` = '.(int)$id
        'AND p.`active` <> 1 AND p.on_sale <> 1'
    );

    return $total_items;
}
```

And this is shopping-cart.tpl call

{$cart->getTotalItems()|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'|number_format:0}

But the return is 0, of course into my basket i have products with and without discount.

What is wrong?

Comment: Firstly, should `_DB_PREFIX_` have underscores at the beginning and end?  If so, then great.  Secondly, the first line of your `WHERE` clause needs another `.` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`(int)$id` will always result in 0 as it is undefined. You need to use `$this->id` to get the cart id.

```
$total_items = (int)Db::getInstance()->getValue('
    SELECT SUM(`quantity`)
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_product`
    WHERE `id_cart` = '.(int)$this->id.
    ' AND p.`active` <> 1 AND p.on_sale <> 1'
);
```